# Java. Find couple of words or phrase from text file and display it

Tags: java

I've some kind of problem finding the words phrase while I enter it reverse/backwards. For example. I'm looking for a name and surname John Lovelock. The program finds the phrase and shows me it. While I enter Lovelock John it doesn't find me the match. How can I acquire this kind of fuction.

Heres what I've got :

```
public class Programa extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTextArea text;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Programa().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Programa() {
        super("Redagavimas");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initialize(); 

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paieska sarase");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Layout());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }

    public void initialize(){

        text = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("Failas");
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Atidaryti");
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Issaugoti");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Uzdaryti");

        JMenuItem[] items = { open, save, exit};
        for(JMenuItem item : items) {
            item.addActionListener(this);

        }

        file.add(open);
        file.add(save);
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(exit);

        bar.add(file);

        add(scroll);
        setJMenuBar(bar);
    }

    public class Layout extends JPanel {

        private JTextField findText;
        private JButton search;
        private JTextArea text;
        private JMenu menu;
        private JMenuItem menuItem;
        private JMenuItem exit;
        private DefaultListModel<String> vieta;
        private DefaultListModel<String> boob;

        public Layout() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel boob = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JPanel kvadratas = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            GridBagConstraints dbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            kvadratas.add(new JLabel("Rasti: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            findText = new JTextField(20);
            kvadratas.add(findText, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.weightx = 4;
            search = new JButton("Ieskoti");
            kvadratas.add(search, gbc);

            text = new JTextArea();
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

            add(kvadratas, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            vieta = new DefaultListModel<>();
            JList list = new JList(vieta);
            add(new JScrollPane(list));
            ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();

            search.addActionListener(handler);
            findText.addActionListener(handler);
        }

        public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                vieta.removeAllElements();

                String searchText = findText.getText();
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader(new File("sarasas.txt")))) {

                    String text = null;
                    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                        if (text.matches(searchText)) {

                            vieta.addElement(text);

                        }

                    }

                } catch (IOException ee) {

                    ee.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Layout.this, "Nera failo", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                }
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Atidaryti")) {
            open();
        }else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Issaugoti")) {
            save(); 
        } else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Uzdaryti")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private void open(){
        try{
            BufferedReader atidarymas = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sarasas.txt"));

            String line;
            while((line = atidarymas.readLine()) != null){
                text.append(line + "\n");
            }

            atidarymas.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void save(){
        try{
            BufferedWriter irasymas = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sarasas.txt"));  

            irasymas.write(text.getText());
            irasymas.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a thinly veiled code request. SO is not a code provider, it is a Q&A site. Show us the work you've done to try and solve your problem, and we'll try to help you the rest of the way.

Comment: You would need to define the logic. There is no obvious reason why a `String` should match itself in reverse.

Comment: [`String.matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) checks to see if the string it is called on matches the given regex. You are not using a regex. Your code is basically doing a more expensive(?) `String.equals(String)`. It should be obvious why `John Lovelock` is not equal to `Lovelock John`.

Comment: I've edited a code sample with full code.

Comment: As @BoristheSpider alluded to - `Lovelock John` is not the reverse of `John Lovelock`. The reverse of `John Lovelock` is `kcolevoL nhoJ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using this `if (text.contains(searchText))` instead of this `if (text.matches(searchText))` as this will allow you to search with only the name or surname. Also in order to search with changed order you should handle this in code. A dummy solution would be the following, of course there will be a better one:

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            vieta.removeAllElements();

            String searchText = findText.getText();
            String[] words = searchText.split(" ");

            StringBuilder sb = null;
            if(words.length > 1) {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(words[1]).append(" ").append(words[0]);
            }

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader(new File("sarasas.txt")))) {

                String text = null;
                while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (text.contains(searchText) || (sb != null && text.contains(sb.toString()))) {

                        vieta.addElement(text);

                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException ee) {

                ee.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Layout.this, "No file", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }
        }
```

Comment: I've tried this one and replacing name with surname and searching doesn't work. I also tried to split the searchtext into 2 strings and writing 2 ifs to search it. Still no success. :(

Comment: Also whats about if you enter a name of one person and a name of 2nd person and it displays them both. how the code should look like or what do I need to use?

Comment: If the names are comma separated you could handle this with a similar way. But as the search requirements are getting more complicated you better replace the file with a database. Then using a form(with first name, last name etc...) it will be much easier to fetch the data you want. Even with the file you can use a different form with more fields(First name, last name).

Comment: Is there a way I could contact u privately?

Comment: Your welcome. I don't know if there is a way. Maybe chat rooms in stackoverflow but I don't know how it works. However, you could ask anything else here. :)

Comment: I was looking through Jframes with database, I found one. I don't know exactly how to express my question but by any chances could u help me develop a search from table by Jframe with database?

By the way back on topic, I got my records like 1. John Lovelock 2. Angelina Jolie, etc. Would there be a way to write a code to display them both when I enter "John Angelina" from a text file ?

Comment: You could separate each name with comma, then split the names(by comma) and search for all different names in the file. If you don't want to use comma in your current code just check if the txt file also contains the values of the array String[] words.